# AWS IoT Core, messages are not being kept with QoS 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot-core

I set my publish topic/payload to QoS =1, but if I subscribe to that topic 15 min from when i publish, the message isn't there. I check cloudwatch, but there isn't a publish-out.

Is there a way to find if someone/thing is connected to my broker with #?...not sure if that would cause things to disappear without a publish-out though.

if I retain the message with the retain flag, that message can get pulled down, without an issue.

Comment: where do you forward your messages, when you receive from clients?

Answer (score 2):

MQTT messages are not queued for new clients (that have never been connected before).

The only way a MQTT broker will queue a message for a client is if they have been previously connected, had a subscription at QOS 1 or 2 and when they reconnect they use the same client id and have the CleanSession flag set to false.